ECS Fargate fluent-bit side-car container exit with code 139
I am trying to use AWS fluent-bit custom image as sidecar for my server container. But each time the service starts up the fluent-bit container stays up for one minute and exits with the 139 code. The only logs that I am seeing are fluent-bit startup logs.
Maybe someone has some suggestions? I am very desperate to get this working, any help is appreciated!
Here is the config I had added:
[SERVICE]
    Log_Level    info
    Parsers_File parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name          tail
    Path          /app/logs/*.log
    Parser        json
    Tag           app_logs

[INPUT]
    Name          forward
    Tag           stderr

[OUTPUT]
    Name          s3
    Match         *
    bucket        <BUCKET>
    region        us-east-1
    total_file_size 5M
    upload_timeout 10m
    use_put_object On
    s3_key_format /fluent-bit-logs/<SERVICE NAME>/%Y/%m/%d/$UUID.log

[OUTPUT]
    Name          stdout
    Match         *

And this is my Dockerfile:
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:stable

# Copy the Fluent Bit configuration file
COPY fluent-bit.conf /fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf

# Command to run Fluent Bit
CMD ["/fluent-bit/bin/fluent-bit", "-c", "/fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf"]

Then in the Task Definition is as follows:
"logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
    "options": {
        "EnableECSLogMetadata": "true",
        "Type": "fluentbit",
        "Name": "firelens"
},

{
    "name": "fluent-bit",
    "image": "<ACC_NUMBER>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/fluent-bit:latest",
    "cpu": 0,
    "portMappings": [],
    "essential": true,
    "environment": [],
    "mountPoints": [],
    "volumesFrom": [],
    "user": "0",
    "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
            "awslogs-group": "/firelens/fluent-bit",
            "awslogs-create-group": "true",
            "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "fluent-bit"
        },
        "secretOptions": []
    },
    "systemControls": [],
    "firelensConfiguration": {
        "type": "fluentbit",
        "options": {
            "config-file-type": "file",
            "config-file-value": "/fluent-bit/etc/fluent-bit.conf"
        }
    }
}

Tried modifying memory of the service
Tried changing the configurations
